# What is calling the Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the [Sass-Bootstrap](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) gem in my project and have the following in my `application.js` file.

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-scrollspy
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-dropdown 
//= require_tree
```

I'm including the following markup in my `application.html.erb` file to utilise the modal feature.

```
<div class="modal" id="loginModal">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Sign in</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name),:html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
                    <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
                    <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
                    <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn' %>
                <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

But for some reason. The modal shows even when theres no javascript/coffescript in any other file...what is calling it? Is it default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="loginModal">
```

Comment: I know from personal struggle. I found it not very well documented.